# Python: How to merge AND sum list values based on some criteria

Tags: python, arrays, list, api, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.6. I've some result from an API call like this:

```
[
  { "order_id": 51128352, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": -1.74 },
  { "order_id": 51128352, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": 13.88 },
  { "order_id": 50290147, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": -1.74 },
  { "order_id": 50290147, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": 20.34 },
  { "order_id": 50320149, "item_id": 13397933, "amount": -5.78 },
  { "order_id": 50320149, "item_id": 13397933, "amount": 23.12 }
]
```

Now, my first goal is to merge the list values AND sum the "amount" value WHERE "order_id" is same. So, the results should be something like this:

```
[
  { "order_id": 51128352, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": 12.14 },
  { "order_id": 50290147, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": 18.6 },
  { "order_id": 50320149, "item_id": 13397933, "amount": 17.34 }
]
```

Once, I get this result now I want to merge this new list values AND sum the "amount" value WHERE "item_id" is same. PLUS I also want to remove "order_id" from the result, since then it would be irrelevant. So, the results should be something like this:

```
[
  { "item_id": 17811608, "amount": 30.74 },
  { "item_id": 13397933, "amount": 17.34 }
]
```

How should I do it?

Comment: What did you tried in coding?

Comment: I was thinking of a "for in" loop statement with nested conditions, but I don't think it's the correct way, since inside each occurrence of "for in" loop we'll have access to only single list value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define `get_order_id` as a function used to sort your input and as a key to `itertools.groupby` (input could be unsorted order_id-wise and `groupby` wouldn't work properly in that case)

Once grouped, just rebuild a list of simplified dicts, with `order_id` and `amount` as keys, and the sum of amounts for `amount` value.

```
l = [
  { "order_id": 51128352, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": -1.74 },
  { "order_id": 50290147, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": -1.74 },
  { "order_id": 50290147, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": 20.34 },
  { "order_id": 50320149, "item_id": 13397933, "amount": -5.78 },
  { "order_id": 51128352, "item_id": 17811608, "amount": 13.88 },
  { "order_id": 50320149, "item_id": 13397933, "amount": 23.12 }
]

import itertools

get_order_id = lambda x : x["order_id"]

result = [{'amount':  sum(x['amount'] for x in r), 'item_id' : k} 
          for k,r in itertools.groupby(sorted(l,key=get_order_id),key=get_order_id)]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[{'amount': 18.6, 'item_id': 50290147}, {'amount': 17.34, 'item_id': 50320149}, {'amount': 12.14, 'item_id': 51128352}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to work, however, the "item_id" in the result has "order_id" values instead of "item_id" values.